# Infinite random number animation as div

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, generator

I need an animated infinite random number generator.
Would be great in a div.

How is that possible with maybe JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: What is an "infinite random number generator"? The adjective "infinite" is not typically used with "random number generator" in computer programming. Most random number generators cycle through a finite set of numbers (e.g. 64 bit numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use odometer (https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/) to animate a number changing. It has different themes to control look and feel.

And if you're looking for it to infinitely change to a random number, you can set it to run on an interval.

So you could have html as follows:

```
<div id="odometer" class="odometer">123</div>
```

Then in your JS file, you would just change the innerHTML of the element, and odometer would handle the animation.

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('odometer').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
}, 2000);
```

See the fiddle below for demo (altered from the fiddle from their github):

http://jsfiddle.net/4wtz8paL/2/